# Decorating a provided instance in dagger

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

If you are using Dagger 2 for dependency injection, is it possible to create a provider that modifies an instance provided by a second provider without modifying the second provider?

Say that I have a preexisting interface `Foo` that looks like this:

```
interface Foo {
    String getName();
    void setName(String name);
}
```

I also have a preexisting provider that can create instances of Foo.

```
@Module
class FooModule {
    @Provide Foo provideFoo() {
        ...
    }
}
```

I now want to create something like this:

```
class DecoratedFooProvider {
    @Provide Foo provideFoo(ObjectGraph graph) {
        final Foo original = graph.get(Foo.class);
        original.setName("A common default name");
        return original;
    }
}
```

I can't use the `@Named()`-qualifier since I want to change the behavior of existing components by modifying what configuration of Foo they receive.

Comment: `ObjectGraph` looks like dagger (1). Are you sure this is about dagger 2?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I am using Dagger 1. Do you know if it is possible in 1 or 2?